# How can I install Gnome 3 on Debian Squeeze?

Tags: debian, gnome, gnome3

I would like to replace Gnome 2 with Gnome 3, but I do not want to upgrade from Squeeze to Wheezy. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are currently no plans to backport Gnome 3 to Squeeze. You *can* (though you **shouldn't**) install Gnome 3 from `testing`:

1. Open `/etc/apt/sources.list` in your favourite text editor
2. Add the line `deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main` at the end of the file
3. Run `apt-get update` to update APT's lists
4. Upgrade the `gnome-core` package from your favourite APT frontend

This should get you Gnome 3 in a Squeeze-Wheezy hybrid. However, following the steps above is not recommended since mixing two releases is a Bad Thing. While it *may* work, it *may* also leave you with a broken system.

What are the reasons keeping you from upgrading from Squeeze to Wheezy? Fixing those reasons might be easier and safer than creating the above-mentioned Squeeze-Wheezy hybrid

Answer (score 1):

You will need to install aptitude and tasksel before install gnome. I followed this page and it works on Debian Squeeze too. http://namhuy.net/1085/install-gui-on-debian-7-wheezy.html

Aptitude is an Ncurses based FrontEnd to Apt, the debian package manager.

Tasksel is a tool that installs multiple related packages as a co-ordinated “task” onto your system.

```
# apt-get install aptitude tasksel
```

Install gnome on debian

```
# tasksel install gnome-desktop --new-install
```